# Invalid index to scalar variable error when iterating through percentile list

Tags: python, python-2.7, scalar

```
Percentile = []

for j in myTuple:
  Percentile.append(stats.percentileofscore(myTuple,j))

print Percentile
```

When I run the code above I get the following output:

> [46.989397879575918, 11.102220444088818, 12.12242448489698, 55.151030206041206, 48.829765953190638,...]

Then when I try iterate through the list I created as written below I receive the error "IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable."

```
for l in Percentile:
  print l[0]
```

Why does this happen and how should I iterate through the calculated percentile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Percentile` is a list(of `float`) here and when you iterate over the elements of a list and print each element you must use :

```
for l in percentile:
    print l
```

Since all the elements are `floats`, so using `[n]` on a float object is raising the error.